# My bash script on my MacBook can not get the stdout of grep

Tags: bash, grep, stdout

I have tried a dozen variations on this, without getting results:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $1;
history | grep $1  | cat > /tmp/hsg_output ;
cat /tmp/hsg_output;
```

I create this on my MacBook Pro. I store it as /usr/local/bin/hsg. I chmod it 0777. If I run:

```
which hsg
```

Then I see:

```
/usr/local/bin/hsg
```

This line correctly outputs my argument:

```
echo $1;
```

If, in my terminal window, I run this line on its own:

```
history | grep upstream  | cat > /tmp/hsg_output ;
```

Then I can:

```
cat /tmp/hsg_output
```

And I see what I expect, which is a history of every time I've pushed my local git repo to its upstream repo.

But when I run this script, nothing appears in /tmp/hsg_output .

Actually, /tmp/hsg_output gets overwritten every time I run "hsg". So the script is correctly writing to /tmp/hsg_output, but it has nothing to write.

I've also tried:

```
history | grep $1  > /tmp/hsg_output ;
```

Which also fails to work (or rather, writes an empty stdin to the the file.

Why am I not able to capture the stdout of grep?

Comment: Often `history` doesn't work inside a script. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/history-command-inside-bash-script) for a related question on U&L (also, you don't need semicolons and the last line you try without the extra `cat` should work fine and be cleaner)

Comment: Thanks, Eric. That other link had the info I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The bash running your script is considered non-interactive, so the history command is silently ignored.

If you really want this functionality:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
grep $1 $HISTFILE > /tmp/hsg_output
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the history file buffer might not be flushed, so it could well appear to be empty.   `history -a` should flush it, but that has to be done *before* the script is run.

Comment: $HISTFILE seems to be empty on my Mac.